# Visual Studio 2022 - asp.net web application - Target Framework missing .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have a ASP.net Web application and have been advised to use .NET core rather than .NET 4

From the Visual Studio 2022 Installer I have installed .NET Core 3.1 Runtime:-
[image]

But when I go to the "Web applications" Target Framework its not an option:-
[image]

If I were to have a "Windows Form app" then the .NET Core is available:
[image]

Can I use .NET Core in a "ASP.net Web application"?

If so any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

tia

Comment: I believe you have picked the "ASP.Net Web Application (.Net Framework)" from the "New Project" menu, instead of picking the "ASP.Net Core Web Application". Therefore, you only have access to the .Net Frameworks - and not the core versions

Comment: I think @Julien hit the nail on the head. When you start a new application you've probably selected to use .Net Framework instead of .Net Core / Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- you need to verify if you have installed framework 4.8 or oldest
link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48

2.- when you create the proyect it shoult see like this

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9d2E.png)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Does this mean I can't toggle an existing ASP.net Web application from .NET 4 to .NET  Core and therefore have to create a New "ASP.Net Core" Web application and some how transfer my existing Web Pages etc?

Comment: I don't think there is an "easy" way to do it - though, they have some migration paths available, depending on how bit your project might be - I guess :)

Comment: @Julien
.Net Core page extentions are .cshtml and I have .aspx
I'm using AjaxControlToolKit and Crystal Reports. 

It's not look easy as you say.

Comment: .net core is a whole new version of the .net runtimes, and also has VERY little (near none) depedancies on windows code. So, no, you can't just swap out a whole runtime built up over the last 20 years with dependences on windows, and then adopt the new .net core runtimes for a asp.net webforms application. For asp.net webforms, you have to use .net framework, not .net core. (so, yes, your last and most up to date version of .net framework is and will be 4.8. So, no, there is no automatic conversion here, and if you want to use .net core, then you have to dump "web forms" and re-write.

Comment: If you want you can adopt .net core, and thus you be using MVC, and not web forms. There is no graphical designer in MVC, and there never was. So, web forms can't use .net core runtimes, they have to use and rely on .net framework ones. There is also no automatic conversion to MVC, and thus you have to re-write and re-build your application if you want to use .net core. We have quite a bit of web forms applications, and in fact like how they work, but we are limited to .net 4.8